# How to parse JSON in android using GSON by using Serialized name?

Tags: android, json, gson

Visit API here https://www.kullabs.com/api/v1/lessons/8  in this API I need to display units_name. I have successfully displayed subjects_name.

Here are my classes

```
public class ScienceWrapper {
    @SerializedName("subject_id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("subject_name")
    public String sub_name;
    @SerializedName(value="unit_details")
    public ArrayList<Science> plist=new ArrayList<>();

}

public class Science {
    @SerializedName("unit_name")
    public String lessonName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some sample JSON, just use this awesome website to generate the GSON classes for you:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: ok thanks for the link! but do you have any idea how to parse the array into array? should i need to use root key to parse inner array! does it understand what I need to parse! can you make me unsderstand how this parsing is working in GSON